# VSCode: Header files within subdirectories of the workspace folder aren't seeing header files in other directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, intellisense, include-path

I'm ready to throw in the towel and just pool all header files and cpp files in a single directory, but I know how insane that is. I've tried listing each individual directory by name (removing `${workspaceFolder}/**`) and replacing it with `${workspaceFolder}/SomeDir1` all the way to `SomeDirN` but it doesn't matter. *Header files within subdirectories of the workspace folder cannot see header files within other subdirectories of the workspace folder that are of different branches.* For example, if I had:

```
${workspaceFolder}/main.cpp
${workspaceFolder}/DirA/a.h
${workspaceFolder}/DirB/b.h
```

and `b.h` included `a.h`, I will get include errors. Yet, `main.cpp` can include `a.h` and `b.h` with no issues. (Also `a.h` cannot include `b.h`). What's weird, is that intellisense seems to *see*  them, but can't include them. And I've tried, within `b.h` to say `#include "../DirA/a.h"` but that didn't work, either.

Current `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/SDL2/"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "forcedInclude": []
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Current `tasks.json` (in case it's relevant. It's only been modified slightly):

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "-fpermissive",
        "${fileDirname}/*/*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "-l",
        "SDL2",
        "-l",
        "SDL2main",
        "-static-libgcc",
        "-static-libstdc++"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "/usr/bin"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
    }
  ]
}
```

also, include errors do not pop up when `main.cpp` includes files in any subdirectories, or when any file within those subdirectories includes files within the same folder.

Also, please don't blow flames my way over the `-fpermissive` flag, I was following a tutorial online to play around with SDL2 and had to set it. I'm not happy about it. I hope this isn't a duplicate question (I looked around *a lot*) and that it's detailed enough and appropriate; it's my first time actually *asking*  something on here.

Comment: have you find a solution to this? i believe i am having the same problem. I think it might have something to do with `-I` parameter